# How to install Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm having trouble getting a test instance of Laravel 5.0 up and running so I can assist with this transition.

1) Creating a new app from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop leads to the following error when running `composer install`.

```
{"error":
    {"type":"ErrorException",
     "message":"Undefined index: timezone",
     "file":"\/Projects\/indatus\/dispatcher-test-app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php",
     "line":167}
}
{"error":
    {"type":"ErrorException",
     "message":"Undefined index: timezone",
     "file":"\/Projects\/indatus\/dispatcher-test-app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php",
     "line":167}}
```

Am I completely missing something?

**UPDATE: This question/answer was only relevant when Laravel 5 was in the development stage.  You should now reference the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master) for how to install Laravel**

Comment: Why not be patient and use a stable release?

Comment: @AliGajani I have a package that I need to update to work with L5

Comment: Can take a look this link that can help you to know installation of laravel from the beginning.... http://www.tisuchi.com/laravel-5-series-episode-1-install-laravel-5/

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As Laravel 5 is already final release, to install it, you should run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test-laravel-5-project --prefer-dist
```

in your console. `test-laravel-5-project` is the name of your project you can call it anyway you want - for example myblog, myapp etc. Laravel files will be put inside this directory

You can also use alternative method using

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

and then running

```
laravel new test-laravel-5-project
```

For detailed info you should look at [official Laravel installation notes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel)

---

***The below answer is being kept only for historical reasons and it was valid when Laravel 5 still was in its development stages. You should now only use the method mentioned above***

I've just tested this and there are two ways of installing Laravel 5:

**One-step method**

You just run:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test-laravel-5-project dev-develop --prefer-dist
```

and composer will create the whole directory structure. In above command `test-laravel-5-project` is your project name - you can of course name it as you want (composer will create directory with this name and put all Laravel5 files inside this directory)

**Multi-step method**

1. Download https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop with option `Download ZIP`
2. Unpack it in web directory
3. Run `composer update` (not `composer install`) in directory where you unpacked your ZIP file

Using both methods when you run URL for your project in the browser (for example `http://localhost/projects/test-laravel-5-project/public` depending on your webserver settings ) you will get standard Laravel website `You have arrived.`

Both methods should work well. Give either one a try, whichever works best for you.

Comment: How did you know to use `test-laravel-5-project`?  Lucky guess or found it documented somewhere?  I wasn't able to find it...

Comment: @Webnet `test-laravel-5-project` is the name of project you want to create. You can put here anything you want for example `dating` if you are creating Dating site and so on. I've just edited my answer to make it clear

Comment: I have tried this: `composer create-project laravel/laravel test-laravel-5-project dev-develop --prefer-dist` with no success, only downloading from github and running composer update has worked.

Comment: @AdemirNuno And what result you got after running this command?

Comment: Got: `[InvalidArgumentException]                                        
  Could not find package laravel-laravel with version dev-develop.`

Comment: @AdemirNuno Are you sure you used exact same command? From your error it seems you used `laravel-laravel` instead of `laravel/laravel` after `create-project`

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek really, I was typing it wrong. So simple mistake, thanks a lot.

Comment: It works, i think i accidentally marked another answer as correct on my phone when i meant to upvote

Comment: fyi, this stopped working: 
Installation request for laravel/framework ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.x-dev].

Comment: @Tobias I've just tested it and the command I gave in my answer works without a problem

Comment: I've run this command and it works perfect: `composer create-project laravel/laravel my_app_name dev-develop --prefer-dist`

Comment: inside the project folder you could try `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` in terminal

Comment: In third method we need to execute php artisan key:generate or else we will get and exception of CSR access token and also we need to set up .env file

Comment: What does "dev-develop" mean / refer to?

Comment: This [post](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/93e98d5d-ec9e-464c-894b-e2ac62fe1203) can be helpful with this solution

Answer (score 8):

Go to CLI and enter following command line. make sure composer is already installed.

`$composer create-project laravel/laravel <yourdirectryname> dev-develop`
It will ask you a question about removing .git files enter Y then.
change the directory to

`$cd <yourdirectoryname>`
then enter following command

$ php artisan -V

you will be able to see following message.

Laravel Framework version 5.0-dev
means you have installed laravel 5 successfully!

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from where you want to store your project

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <projectname>
```

Remember, it will download the latest version of laravel application from git.

if you are using linux then give permission to **bootstrap/cache** and **storage** by running the command `chmod 777 -R <dir name>` from root of your laravel project

Answer (score 0):

> composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install laravel globally in your system by this command

**composer global require laravel/installer**
then you can install laravel by three ways, 
1) Go to laravel [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) Reqosritory and download it's zip, and second it get ssh or Https url and install it from CMD or Git bash
 2) open Git bash just write **laravel new** there, this will download the latest laravel verision
3) open cmd or git bash and write there.
**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**
if you want to install some old version then you can write the mention the version in last.
**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog 5.2.***