# Laravel create 5.2 version project issue

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm starting a new project and i want to start it with a new version of laravel. I don't want to upgrade and old version.

How can I create a Laravel **5.2** project?

Where is my problem and what did I do:

I installed laravel 5.1 with

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname
```

also `laravel new projectname` has the same problem.

This is the composer file after installing a fresh project

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
...
```

I also tried with

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2.0 projectname
```

but i got this error

```
could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.2.0.
```

I tried with `composer self-update` same problem
I read laravel 5.2 documentation. It is officially out

Comment: I think you need to add `"minimum-stability": "beta"` to your composer.json

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949281/3593996 the same question was asked when Laravel 5 was in develop version.

Now if you want to create 5.2 project you need to use `dev-develop` as version in composer create project:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name dev-develop
```

But if you want to install 5.1 version you can use

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.1.*
```

or simple:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

Similar is for older versions, for example:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.0.*
```

or

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*
```

When Laravel 5.2 will be released as stable, you will be able to install it using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.2.*
```

or simple

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

and using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name dev-develop
```

you will probably install development version of Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 5):

The [Laravel 5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation) have the correct solution here:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that Laravel 5.2.0 is still a beta version, not a stable version. So, for the fresh install:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name **dev-develop**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Today if you do the usual install it gets you 5.2.23

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 1):

the same happened to me. As my php version was lower than 5.5, the composer automatically downloaded the laravel version that was compatible to my php version and it was laravel 5.0.16. After installing php 5.5 it worked.