# How to install Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I heard Laravel 5.4 will be unveiled tomorrow.

How to install (Laravel 5.4) the Beta version?

Do you know the new features?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Laravel 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948560/how-to-install-laravel-5-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to install Laravel. One of the simplest ways would be to install through composer with the command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel MyAppName`.

All of the documentation for installing laravel 5.4 can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

The new features are covered on laracasts and on the docs. Here is a link to some of the new features: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 21):

You can download Laravel 5.4 with this command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName 5.4 
# or use `5.4.*` for latest version
```

Answer (score 9):

Go to your respective server folder like xampp or wamp with cmd and type the given command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName 5.4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <project_name> "5.4.*" --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Install composer from here: https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Make Sure Your Server meeting these requirements
   (related to installed version 
   **Laravel 5.4**) - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#installation:

   - PHP >= 5.6.4
   - OpenSSL PHP Extension
   - PDO PHP Extension
   - Mbstring PHP Extension
   - Tokenizer PHP Extension
     XML PHP Extension
3. Download Laravel Installer using this code:

   `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
4. Create Laravel project using this code:

   - Install custom version (**Use this one**):

   `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"`

   - Install default version:

   `laravel new blog`

Answer (score 3):

There is two way for installing laravel new fresh project in our system.

1. With the composer
2. With the Laravel installer

**Method 1: The composer**

1. We have first need to install composer globally in our system.
   [Download the composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and install it.
2. Now we create a directory in our system to store the new project.
3. Go to the directory and open the command line. Simply run this command to create a new project: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`. It will create a blog folder in your directory. It will take a couple of time.

Ok, we got the new blog project by the composer.

**Method 2: The Laravel installer**

Laravel provides the convenient way to install Laravel new project.

1. We install Laravel installer globally: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
2. Make sure to place the directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the executable can be located by your system.
3. For create new project with Laravel installer we just have run: `laravel new blog`

For more information, you can check [Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation) which will help you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Step1:  open the link => https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Step2: [Download & install  => composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Step3:  Open Command Prompt

Step4: Change your path to  Xampp,  go to your htdocs and enter `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel =5.4`

Comment: please format your answer properly so that the readability is improved

Answer (score 3):

In windows CTRL + SHIFT + Right click your folder where you want to install your laravel project and then you will find command prompt. and then just type in command prompt

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName 5.4
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install composer
   For windows, [Click here to Download composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)

   For debain, Go to terminal,
       `cd /usr/src`

   `$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

   Type `composer --version` in terminal.

   For ubuntu just enter `sudo apt-get install composer`

If you are using `Xampp` then go to your `htdocs` and enter `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test-app`

Your laravel framework will download with name `test-app` the version will be `5.4`.

Follow the documentation for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

For installing the laravel any version just go to the laravel documentation and follow the instruction which they provided.Just select the version from the Top right Corner.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

or

You can follow the following guidelines for installing the laravel 5.4

1. Download and install the composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. After that go to the command line and travel the directory where you want to install the Laravel and Run the Following command

   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"

Installing Laravel Through Composer is a best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and run one of the following commands:

1. For installing any 5.4.x latest version:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel this-app "5.4.*"

2. For installing 5.4.0 version:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel this-app 5.4

That's it.